# Parent and child with Panda in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file with more than 10000 rows, now I want to create a new column which shows the dependency between parent and child. based on the mentioned rules and policies which  exists as below:

1. The unique code which determine  and show that the data relates to which family is ***Team***.
2. If the ***Position*** is C , the ***Parent*** field must be fulfilled with it's relative position.
3. If the ***Position*** is PF, the ***Child*** field must be fulfilled with it's position but if any other ***Position*** exists (except C and PF) it must fulfilled as it's relative positin too.
4. Any other ***Position*** exists the Child must be fulfilled.

Existing data in CSV:

```
Team        Position
Atlanta Hawks   C
Atlanta Hawks   PF
Atlanta Hawks   PG
Atlanta Hawks   SF
Atlanta Hawks   SG
```

Result:

```
Parent Child
C         PF
PF        PG
PF        SF
PF        SG
```

I try to work with Panda in this regard. below code run fine for first condition. I appreciate if any one helps me for modifiying this code?

```
  import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\nba.csv")
    
    gdf = df['Team']
    gdf.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\nba-dependency.csv')
    for g in gdf:
        df.loc[df['Position']=='C','Parent']=df['Position']
        df.loc[df['Position']=='PF','Parent']=df['Position']
    
    df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\result.csv')
```

Comment: I have tried to solve this but found that the question is pretty unclear, you talk about dependency field but never show how the actual output should look, please add the desired output for given data, I do not understand what "what it should be" data stand for as well, is that some df where you store parent and child tuples for translation here? I guess so as it has different number of lines than your data

Comment: Yes you are right. I correct the content.

Comment: I have the Existing data in excel and I want to change it by  the code and conditions to the final result which I show in the content.

Comment: 2 columns with the header of parent and child will be added. If the value of position is C the parent field will be fulfilled by C. If the value of position is PF , C will be the parent an PF will be child. If any other field except C and PF exists. PF will be the parent and other fields will be the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, this should be the correct approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"team":["ah","ah","ah","ah","ah"],"position":["C","PF","PG","SF","SG"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Parent"] = ["C" if x=="C" or x=="PF" else "PF" for x in df["position"]]
df["Child"] = df["position"]
print(df)
```

Output here will be

> ```
>   team position Parent Child
> 0   ah        C      C     C
> 1   ah       PF      C    PF
> 2   ah       PG     PF    PG
> 3   ah       SF     PF    SF
> 4   ah       SG     PF    SG
> ```

I am not entirely sure if the first row is as you expect, you probably wanted to remove this row (you do not show it in result, drop it if so), the rest seem to look as you defined.

Comment: This works perfectly correct,I appreciate it. but just one question as I have about 10000 rows with different teams, PF belongs to ah team, now if I have PF in bh team is it possible to add another column which is the combination of team.Parent and team,Child? team.Parent will be bh.C and team.child will be bh.PF?

Comment: do you mean something like `df["combined"] = df["team"]+df["Parent"]+df["Child"]`?